# Traffic from logged in users with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I would like to separate out the traffic between logged in users and users who have not logged into our site.  The Sensr.net login link in the top right of the page turns into the user name when they are logged in.  Is there a way to use this DOM state to segment the GA stats?

We have integer user ids from our database, should we use [custom variables](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables) and put the Sensr.net UID into one of the custom variables?

Answer (score 2):

Advance segments and Event Tracking is not wrong, you can use them creatively. But custom variables are there to track situations like this.

There are three main options such as Visitor Level, Session Level and Page Level. Visitor Level is recommended for this situation.

I will submit some referrals which will be very useful.

1)  http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2012/08/28/20-ways-use-custom-variables/

2)  http://online-behavior.com/analytics/custom-variables-segmentation

Comment: Wouldn't session level be more useful for this? A given user may or may not be logged in during different sessions.

Comment: Hi, Please apply which you think will work for you.The main different is Visitor Level — this will modify the visitors' cookies for as long as they use the same browser and device and do not erase cookies.   Session Level — this modifies the visitors' cookies for the period of time during which the visitor is active on the site. Very useful to track internal campaigns, such as banners on the homepage.Please apply the suitable option,Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you create a new advanced segment where one of the conditions (or the only one for that matter) is that they should've visited a certain url, i.e. login confirmed? Or when it's ajax based you could try creating an event for that action and create a segment for that specific event.